# Array of objects to object using properties from the objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

Sorry if this is a bit confusing, but I have this array:

```js
[
      {
        name: 'id',
        type: 'string',
        primary: true
      },
      {
        name: 'notes',
        type: 'text',
        default: '[]'
      },
      {
        name: 'reminders',
        type: 'text',
        default: '[]'
      }
    ]
```

How would I turn it into

```
{
  notes: '[]',
  reminders: '[]'
}
```

? Here's the logic: Any index with a `default` property, set the key in the new object to the index's `name`, and set the value to the index's `default`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it with reduce

```js
var array = [
      {
        name: 'id',
        type: 'string',
        primary: true
      },
      {
        name: 'notes',
        type: 'text',
        default: '[]'
      },
      {
        name: 'reminders',
        type: 'text',
        default: '[]'
      }
    ]

var result = array.reduce((prev, el) => {
   if (el.default) {
       prev[el.name] = el.default
   }
   return prev;
},{})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce`:

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'string',
    primary: true
  },
  {
    name: 'notes',
    type: 'text',
    default: '[]'
  },
  {
    name: 'reminders',
    type: 'text',
    default: '[]'
  }
];

const obj = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => curr.default ? { ...acc,
  [curr.name]: curr.default
} : acc);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: The result of this approach is `{name: "id", type: "string", primary: true, notes: "[]", reminders: "[]"}` and is not what the OP asked for

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
      {
        name: 'id',
        type: 'string',
        primary: true
      },
      {
        name: 'notes',
        type: 'text',
        default: '[]'
      },
      {
        name: 'reminders',
        type: 'text',
        default: '[]'
      }
];

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  data
    .filter(it => "default" in it)
    .map(it => ([it.name, it.default]))
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```js
// Your initial array
const initialArray = [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'string',
        primary: true
    },
    {
        name: 'notes',
        type: 'text',
        default: '[]'
    },
    {
        name: 'reminders',
        type: 'text',
        default: '[]'
    }
];

// Array just with items that haves a default value
const itensWithDefaultValue = initialArray.filter(item => Object.keys(item).includes('default'));

// Object to save items 
let objectWithValues = {};

// Save items in object with name and you default value
itensWithDefaultValue.map(item => objectWithValues[item.name] = item.default);

console.log(objectWithValues);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could spread new objects into a single object.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'id', type: 'string', primary: true }, { name: 'notes', type: 'text', default: '[]' }, { name: 'reminders', type: 'text', default: '[]' }],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...data.map(({ name, default: d }) => d && { [name]: d }));

console.log(result);
```